# R can't add column to a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I tried to add a column to multiple data.frames in a list. But for some reason, it doesn't allow me to do it.

My code to add the column:

```
calculatereturn <- function(x){
  return <- numeric(60)
  x<-cbind(x,return)
  x[1,3] <- NA
  for(j in 2:60) x[j,3]=(x[j,2]-x[(j-1),2])/x[j-1,2]
  x<-na.omit(x)
}
lapply(datalist,calculatereturn)
```

The output shows the new column

calculatereturn <- function(x){

```
+   return <- numeric(60)
+   x<-cbind(x,return)
+   x[1,3] <- NA
+   for(j in 2:60) x[j,3]=(x[j,2]-x[(j-1),2])/x[j-1,2]
+   x<-na.omit(x)
+ }
> lapply(datalist,calculatereturn)
$ADM.csv
         Date Adj.Close       return
2  2007-06-01     33.09 -0.055650712
3  2007-07-01     33.60  0.015412451
4  2007-08-01     33.70  0.002976280
```

But when I actually call up the data frame.

```
> datalist$ADM.csv
         Date Adj.Close
1  2007-05-01     35.04
2  2007-06-01     33.09
3  2007-07-01     33.60
```

It's like the codes just don't work.

Comment: Maybe you just need assign the new value to original obj `datalist <- lapply(datalist,calculatereturn)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solves the problem! But why is that? When I use the  'lapply' function, shouldn't the new values be assigned to the obj already?

Comment: No. `apply` won't modify the orignal obj, it returns a new copy.